# If $R$ is a ring with unit element $1$ and $φ$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a ring with unit element $1$ and $φ$ is a homomorphism
of $R$ into an integral domain $R'$
such that kernel of $φ$ is different from
$R$, prove that φ(1) is the unit element of $R'$.

---

could you give me tips to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(1)=b$ is not zero, since the image is not zero. We have $\phi(1\cdot 1)=\phi(1)\cdot\phi(1)$ implies that $b=b\cdot b$ and $b(1-b)=0$. Since $R'$ is an integral domain and $b\neq 0$, $b=1$.